# How a wrapper with img can take all the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 div, one is the wrapper slideshow with img and second is content who appears after the slideshow. So I would like to made a fullscreen slideshow that not use property position absolute or fixed to keep the flow of content. Sorry for my english, I'm french.

```
<div id="slide">
    <img src="bg.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried sizing the image to 100% width and height? Your div ofcourse has to accommodate for this aswell, and your body and HTML tags must also be 100% in width and height...

```
<img width="100%" height="100%" src="bg.jpg" alt="" />
```

Edit: You can use this stylesheet, to get what you asked in your original question:

```
<style>
    *
    {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }

    body, html
    {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }

    #slide img 
    {
        width:100%;
    }
</style>
```

If you want more control (like you mention later on in your comment), you will need to use javascript to dynamically size your image according to the width and height of your users' screen.

Comment: Yeah, but she doesn't conserve the ratio of image. I can use 100% for the div but not for the image.

Comment: If you want to conserve the image ratio, just set only height or only the width of the image to 100%, your browser will adjust the other value to ration. You will have to decide if you want the image to be full-width or full-height.

Comment: I would like to have full-width up-to 1600px and full-height with -30px at bottom

Comment: Hi Atu, please look ak my edit on the answer. The stylesheet does waht you asked in the original question. For more control (like a width up to 1600px and a 30px offset at the bottom, you will need javascript.) The -30 px might work if you give the image a padding-bottom or a margin-bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but all function I saw, they used position absolute, top and left property to crop the image.

Comment: You can ofcourse use {position:absolute; top:0; left:0;} to place the image in the top left corner of the screen, but there is no way to specify a 100% width up to 1600px and bottom margin of 30px without using javascript to check what the users' window width and height actually is. Do you control the size of these images yourself, and are they all the same size?

Comment: All my image has same same size, but I need to crop them, if I want to resize and take all the windows.

Comment: Like this http://www.alsacreations.com/xmedia/tuto/exemples/extensible/demo-jquery/

Comment: Is very special, but I can't use position absolute, and I need to vertical align bottom. You had something ?

Comment: :) to align an element to the bottom, the only way is to use position:absolute and use bottom:0. Unless you know the exact screen size this is not possible with CSS, you will need javascript to query the screen/window size and scale your image accordingly (and to ratio).